# Swap elements of a hex int in Java

Tags: java, substring

I'd like to swap the red and blue color values of a pixel. The method that's supposed to do this receives pixels as int 0xAARRGGBB where AA is the hex value for alpha and r, g, b for the colors, e.g. 0xFF0000FF for a fully opaque blue.

I'd convert the value to a string, then use substring() to cut it up, splice it back together in the modified order and turn the result back into an int. This seems unelegant and doesn't work:

```
public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int pixel) {

    int filteredPixel;
    String s, a, r, g, b, res;
        s = Integer.toString(pixel);            
        a = s.substring(2,4);//alpha                
        r = s.substring(4,6);//r
        g = s.substring(6,8);//g
        b = s.substring(8,10);//b

    res = "0x" + a + b + g + r;
    filteredPixel = Integer.parseInt(res);

    return filteredPixel;
```

The reason why it doesn't work seems to be substring(8,10). Code after that line isn't executed. It does work with substring(8,9), but that cuts off blues second hex value. I wouldn't know how to look this up on my own, so, could someone explain it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace

```
s = Integer.toString(pixel);
```

with

```
s = Integer.toString(pixel, 16);
a = s.substring(0,2);//alpha
r = s.substring(2,4);//r
g = s.substring(4,6);//g
b = s.substring(6,8);//b
```

your method should work.

However, a better way is to use bit arithmetic and shifts to perform the rearrangements:

```
int a = (pixel >>> 24) & 0xFF;
int r = (pixel >>> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (pixel >>>  8) & 0xFF;
int b = (pixel >>>  0) & 0xFF;

int filteredPixel = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (g << 8) || (r << 0);
```